# Whats wrong with this MySQL query - Left Outer Join

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join, outer-join

I have three tables in my data base, lets call them:
1. value_type
2. values
3. orgs

Each value has a foreign key reference to a value_type and an org. Further, each value type also has a default value.

I am trying to do a left outer join for all orgs such that if a record exists in the value table, it will return the values from that record and if the record does not exist, it will take the default value from the value_type table. However, when I run the following query, it returns nulls for all orgs where the records don't already exist in the value table.

```
SELECT 
    o.id as org_id,
    o.name as org_name,
    case when vals.choice is null then vals.default_value else vals.choice END as select_choice,
    vals.choices as choices
FROM orgs o
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (SELECT 
        v.id as id,
        v.choice as choice,
        v.org_id as org_id,
        v.name as val_name,
        vt.default_value as default_value,
        vt.choices as choices
    FROM value v
    INNER JOIN value_type vt ON v.value_type = vt.id
    WHERE vt.name = 'xyz') vals
ON vals.org_id = o.id
```

Comment: well... if the vals.org_ID doesn't exist for o.id all vals.records will be null so your case statement will always return a Null value for such records. Put another way since there is no record in vals for the org, you can't get at the default this way.

Comment: How do value_type and orgs relate?  how would we know what value type to pick for the org, or is that why you limit to vt.name of 'xyz'?  which would only result in 1 record?

Comment: Usually if you want a default value it's not based on a foreign key relationship, it's a special row that's considered the default, not another column in the same row as the value. You get it with a separate join with the ID of that row. Can you show some sample data and the expected result?

Comment: The *definition* of left join is that if there's no match for an o.id its row is in the output extended by nulls.

Answer (score 1):

Seems odd but perhaps you need to cross join orgs to value_Type then left join to value?

This way ever record from org will list all the value types for a given name; along with the default and then IF a record exists in value, we join specifically to it as well.  coalesce will then pick the first non-null between vals.choice if it exists and the cross join vt.default_value which we know will exist.

```
SELECT 
    o.id as org_id,
    o.name as org_name,
    coalesce(vals.choice, VT.Default_Value)
    VT.choices as choices
FROM orgs o
CROSS JOIN (SELECT id, choices, default_value FROM Value_Type where Name = 'xyz') VT
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (SELECT 
        v.id as id,
        v.choice as choice,
        v.org_id as org_id,
        v.name as val_name,
        v.value_Type
    FROM value v) vals
  ON vals.org_id = o.id
 AND vals.value_type = vt.id
```

Comment: Yes, I did need a cross join and that did it for me.

Answer (score 0):

I would expect something like this:

```
SELECT o.id as org_id,o.name as org_name,
       COALESCE(v.choice, vt.default_value) as select_choice,
       vt.choices as choices
FROM orgs o LEFT JOIN
     value v
     ON v.org_id = o.id LEFT JOIN
     value_types vt
     ON vt.id = v.value_type AND vt.name = 'xyz' ;
```

However, this will still return `NULL` when there is no matching record between `orgs` and `value`.  You don't have a connection between `value_types` and `orgs`.  It has to go through `value`, so a match between `orgs` and `value` is needed.

Comment: If there's no record in value for an org, then how can you get a default from value type since the join is from O-->V-->VT?